# Validation table for data tables

Tags: mysql, validation, datatable, null

I'm new to db design and have a couple of problems.

I have a *job title* field in 3 data tables and need to use a validation table to limit the range of values. My question: Do I need to create a separate validation table for each of the data tables, or can I use only one and link it to all the 3 data tables?

Another question: Is it better to have an optional *Health Professional* field set to Null for a *Trainees* table, or would you recommend to have a validation table with two values:yes,no.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to create a separate validation table for each of the data
>   tables, or can I use only one and link it to all the 3 data tables?

Use one. Each of the other three tables can set a foreign key reference to it.

> Is it better to have an optional Health Professional field set to Null
>   for a Trainees table, or would you recommend to have a validation
>   table with two values:yes,no.

Neither. I think this is a better approach.

- Use a Boolean column.
- Declare it to be `NOT NULL`.
- Set a default value. Use the most common for your app, either
  `DEFAULT TRUE` or `DEFAULT FALSE`.

If you can design without NULLs, you're usually better off.

Answer (score 0):

Validate all string values before insert data into the db, if you're using php consider using:

```
$cc = "1234567891234567";
$max_size = 16;
$string_size = strlen($cc);
if($cc > $max_size )
{
    echo "your string must be < than $max_size characters";
}
```